# Understanding English grammar and proper word usage

Tags: parts-of-speech

Would someone please help me identify the type of each word in the following sentence? In learning Spanish (using Duolingo and lovin' it) I'm realizing my English is "accidentally" good. My knowledge of grammar is embarrassing. A sentence Duolingo used (I personally would never word it this way) was:

> "I am going to tell you something later."

I know the verb is *tell*.
I think the subject is *you*... or is it *I*...
The object might be *something*.
What is *going*?

Anywho, I need to know the type of each word to properly format sentences in Spanish.

Answer (score 2):

> "I am going to tell you something later."

- *`I`* is the subject. The actor performing action.
- *`am going to`* are [auxiliaries to the main verb](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/auxiliary.htm), whose purpose is to define the time the verb is taking place in.
- *`tell`* is the main verb.
- *`you`* is the [indirect object](https://amagicalhour.wordpress.com/reading-and-writing-resources/grammar/sentence-basics-subjects-verbs-objects-adjectives-and-adverbs/). The person for whom the action is taking place.
- *`something`* is the direct object. That of which the subject is talking about.
- *`later`* is an adverb. Further describes the time, which is redundant in this case, since the auxiliary verbs already did that and it's not really providing any additional information.

Comment: sorry, but "am going" is the main verb....there is no auxiliary verb here.